ValueError in LazyClassifier in Python for binary classification Machine Learning Model?
I try to use LazyClassifier to build Machine Learning models with binary target variable.

X_train has 114074 observations and 15 columns
X_test has 48890 observations
y_train has 114074 observations and 15 columns
y_test has 48890 observations

I created custom_metic function like below:
def custom_metric(y_train_true, y_train_pred, y_test_true, y_test_pred):
    accuracy_train = accuracy_score(y_train_true, y_train_pred)
    accuracy_test = accuracy_score(y_test_true, y_test_pred)
    
    f1_beta1_train = f1_score(y_train_true, y_train_pred, beta=1)
    f1_beta1_test = f1_score(y_test_true, y_test_pred, beta=1)
    
    f1_beta2_train = f1_score(y_train_true, y_train_pred, beta=2)
    f1_beta2_test = f1_score(y_test_true, y_test_pred, beta=2)
    
    auc_train = roc_auc_score(y_train_true, y_train_pred)
    auc_test = roc_auc_score(y_test_true, y_test_pred)
    
    precision_train = precision_score(y_train_true, y_train_pred)
    precision_test = precision_score(y_test_true, y_test_pred)
    
    recall_train = recall_score(y_train_true, y_train_pred)
    recall_test = recall_score(y_test_true, y_test_pred)
    
    return {
        'accuracy_train': accuracy_train, 'accuracy_test': accuracy_test,
        'f1_beta1_train': f1_beta1_train, 'f1_beta1_test': f1_beta1_test,
        'f1_beta2_train': f1_beta2_train, 'f1_beta2_test': f1_beta2_test,
        'auc_train': auc_train, 'auc_test': auc_test,
        'precision_train': precision_train, 'precision_test': precision_test,
        'recall_train': recall_train, 'recall_test': recall_test
    }

And then I tried to use LazyClassifier:
cls = LazyClassifier(ignore_warnings=True, custom_metric=custom_metric)
models, predictions = cls.fit(X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test)

Nevertheless, I received Error like below:
ValueError: All arrays must be of the same length


What can I do to avoid that error ?
